# Nullable types and &&

Tags: c#, .net

What is the correct way to handle a Nullable boolean in an if statement?

1:

```
if ((complaint.ChargeSubcontractor ?? false) && x == y)
```

2:

```
if (complaint.ChargeSubcontractor.Value && x == y)
```

3:

```
if ((complaint.ChargeSubcontractor != null && complaint.ChargeSubcontractor.Value) && x == y)
```

Comment: 1 and 3 are fine.  2 should be HasValue && ChargeSubcontractor instead of Value (it's going to throw an NRE otherwise).  It's just a matter of personal style/preference, not one way being "correct."

Comment: I would always use version 1, but only for preference, because I think the coalesce operator indicates both that it is a nullable value and what the default is. But, as said elsewhere, it's personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

Why not

```
if (complaint.ChargeSubcontractor == true && x == y)
```

This will return `false` if `ChargeSubcontractor` is `null`

Answer (score 1):

`ChargeSubcontractor.Value` will throw an exception if `ChargeSubcontractor.HasValue` is false (i.e. if `ChargeSubcontractor` is null), so don't use #2.

Examples #1 and #3 are equivalent but you could use `ChargeSubcontractor == true` for improved readability.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is necessarily a canonical answer, but here is my take:

1: You can replace `complaint.ChargeSubcontractor ?? false` with `complaint.ChargeSubcontractor.GetValueOrDefault(false)`

2: You'll want to check that `complaint.ChargeSubcontractor` actually has a value before calling `.Value`

3: See #1.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (complaint.ChargeSubcontractor.HasValue && complaint.ChargeSubcontractor.Value && x == y)
```

Answer (score 0):

For brevity, I'll make

```
bool? z = complaint.ChargeSubcontractor;
```

If the case of `z == null` is undefined or *should* throw an error, I'd go with:

```
if (z.Value && x == y)
```

If `z == null` should be treated as `z == false`, I'd do the following. **This is the one I'd recommend in most cases.**

```
if (z == true && x == y)
```

Also valid and equivalent to the above, but not as clear and concise IMO:

```
if (z.GetValueOrDefault() && x == y)
if (z != null && z.Value && x == y)
if ((z ?? false) && x == y)
```

My preferred approach also works quite nicely if you're looking for `false` or `null`, not just `true`. Other approaches will require you to change your code more substantially to change the matching value.

```
if (z == true && x == y)
if (z == false && x == y)
if (z == null && x == y)
```